# FormIt troubles

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, formit

I have a FormIt form which forks in one website, but it doesn't work at another at all (same as all forms which I have created or copypasted from the manual). If it's on the top level, it works, if it's in the some sublevel menu it doesn't.
The only thing I have found - after I try to send email the wronk url is loaded - instead of:

```
http://example.com/main-menu/how-to-help-us/informations/test
```

I get:

```
http://example.com/main-menu/how-to-help-us/informations/main-menu/how-to-help-us/informations/test
```

My FormIt call is follwing:

```
[[!FormIt?
       &hooks=`FormItSaveForm, email`
       &successMessage=`Message sent`
       &formName=`cbd_form`
       &validate=`name:required,company:required,phone:required,email:email:required`
       &emailTpl=`cbdReport`
       &emailSubject=`Subject`
       &emailTo=`myemail@gmail.com`
    ]]
```

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/8hJTfCX2

Any ideas what to check?

It's the latest REVO installed. MODX Revolution 2.4.3-pl

Comment: Please add form html code.

Comment: @Vasis thanks for help, updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you forget to add `<base href="[[++site_url]]">` tag to head of your template?